# Prevent line break between two elements in CSS

Tags: css, whitespace

For some basic layout work I'm doing, I'd like links that immediately follow a price to always be shown on the same line as the price. The price text is wrapped in a `<span class="price">` tag while the link uses the buy-link class as in `<a href="/buy" class="buy-link">Buy Now</a>`.

I'm looking for CSS that will automatically prevent line breaking between the `span` and `a` tag but I'm either missing something or it can't be done. I can easily prevent line breaks *within* the two tags - but not between them.

I want to avoid wrapping both tags in a `span` with a `white-space: nowrap` manually and use pure CSS if possible.

**Update:** The HTML looks something like the following. It's not the real code but very similar.

```
<style>
    .price{ font-weight: bold; }
    .buy-link{ color: green; }
</style>

<span class="price">$50</span> <a href="/buy" class="buy-link">Buy Now</a>
```

If the link happens to be near the page edge - or block edge in a `<div>` or `<table>` browsers will wrap the Buy Now link to the next line. Separating the two elements.

Answer (score 13):

Can't you nest the anchor inside the span, like

```
<span class="price"><a href="/buy" class="buy-link">Buy Now</a>&nbsp;Only $19.95!</span>
```

then set the span to `white-space: nowrap`?

Comment: how can it be nested? price should be in `span` and buy-link in `a`.

Comment: @nvl: just look at it. Both those requirements are met. Correct CSS can handle the styling of both. I will edit to show span text.

Comment: This **is** possible. But we cannot force our solution to OP :D. This is OP's preference (to make price hyperlink too).

Comment: @nvl: That's not how I read it. He says the price is in a span and the item is in an anchor tag.

Answer (score 7):

```
<span class="price">$50</span>&nbsp;<a href="/buy" class="buy-link">Buy Now</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution using css method white-space:nowrap**

```
<style>
   div{width:10px;white-space:nowrap;}
  .price{ font-weight: bold; }
  .buy-link{ color: green; }
</style>
<div>
  <span class="price">$50</span>
  <a href="/buy" class="buy-link">Buy Now</a>
</div>​
```

**Solution using HTML method (In case you're not in the mood to use white-space:nowrap;)**

```
    <style>
        .price{ font-weight: bold; }
        .buy-link{ color: green; }
    </style>

    <span class="price">$50</span>&nbsp;<a href="/buy" class="buy-link">Buy&nbsp;Now</a>
<!--Just removing the breaking whitespace between "Buy" and "Now"-->
```

***Just removed the breaking space between "Buy" and "Now" and inserted a nbsp (non-breaking space) so that the break/wrap doesn't occur ***

---

See this fiddle with the wrapping effect: http://jsfiddle.net/8SP2C/2/

See this fiddle with css `white-space:nowrap`: http://jsfiddle.net/8SP2C/1/

See this fiddle with html method : http://jsfiddle.net/8SP2C/3/

Comment: Thanks for the effort - but the requirement is that I don't have to wrap the elements in another tag.

Comment: The <div> was added just for example to demonstrate that fact (in the fiddle) when the parent/bounding box restricts the child inline elements they wrap...to avoid this wrapping we use white-space:nowrap. That <div> could be even <body>, hope you get the point. Please take the effort to at least read the whole thing.

Comment: **<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
white-space:nowrap;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--some other html markup here-->
<span class="price">$50</span>
<a href="/buy" class="buy-link">Buy Now</a>
<!--some other html markup here-->
</body>
</html>**

Your real code would look something like this. Now if you even resize the brower window to the point that the window width is lesser than the text width, even then they will not wrap. I hope that clarifies the internals and idea of white-space:nowrap;

Comment: That would still require adding some parent with whitspace no-wrap. The goal is to define it without depending on any parent settings.

Comment: You will have at the least <body> as your parent, won't you? (you can add nowrap to <body>)...It is actually the parent that is in the first place causing the wrap for its child after all !! (no parent--no children--no wrapping--no using white-space:nowrap)

Comment: That's not a practical solution. Adding nowrap to the body would result in a ridiculously formatted page. The bottom line is it can't be done.

Comment: Check the edited answer...and if its for the sake of argument I can't help it....and lastly the bottom line is "everything can be done" !

Comment: This is the only one that works if the first element should be allowed to wrap. Both must be inline (not inline-block). Then you can get: "thing that is long and 
has a second line with thing after(nbsp here)Thing after"

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested this in all five browsers and it works fine.  You don't need a parent class. To bold something without creating a line break, just do this:

First put this in the head portion of your html:

```
<style type="text/css">
.makeBold /* to only be used with SPAN: (i.e.) <span class="makeBold"></span>  */
{
   font-weight:bold;
   width:122px;    /* This should be the width length of the thing you are bolding */
   white-space:nowrap; 
}
</style>
```

Later in the Body of your HTML you should just use span.

```
<span class="makeBold">BOLD THIS TEXT</span>
```

You can use span inside a Div and stay HTML5 compliant.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

As `<span>` element is meant for *inline* grouping by default, the price and link should be on same line.

I guess some CSS is over-riding it.